# How to drag & drop multi external events into the FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery `FullCalendar`, and using the external events provided with it.
I want to be able to drag and drop multi events (adding several events at the same time) into the `FullCalendar`. I tried to use a checkbox beside every event, but couldn't get the event object to drop it into the `FullCalendar`.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with multi-event? Drag several events to the calendar?

Comment: IMHO it can't be done because when you drag and drop something you just drag ONE thing from point A to B and not several. If you could add a more practical example, maybe I could help you a little more.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna : the main goal is to add more than one event at once..it doesn't have to be by dragging and dropping, as I mentioned above, I may use checkbox for every event and by clicking a button I add the checkd events to the calendar, the propblem is how to get the event objects of these checked events ?..What is the way drag and drop getting event object with it ?

Comment: Multidrag can be done with event-delegation technique. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/terjeto/stT8q/3/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to watch the `FullCalendar` API because it's pretty easy with your perspective. You can read it [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) and it's pretty well documented.

Fullcalendar doesn't allow to add new events directly to the calendar since it needs to be grabbed from somewhere. A feed, a JSON, or whatever.

Since I don't know where do you plan to store your events (you have to do somewhere) I can't provide much more info but the basic idea is the following.

Set `Fullcalendar` to grab events from somewhere (a DB or a text-file proxied with PHP to JSON or whatever).

Then, build your checklist with a button to add them to the calendar. You'll need to build a function which **adds** the info to the source where the calendar feeds. You'll need to use a little bit of Ajax I think. You'll need to ask the user **WHEN** he/she wants to add the event since you'll need to add it to a specific date.

Once the data is at the source, tell `Fullcalendar` to reload and it will show the events now.